# What is the Hubble parameter H(z) dependence on z for an exponential De Sitter expansion a(t)=a(0)exp(Ht)

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

What is the Hubble parameter $H(z)$ dependence on $z$ for an exponential de Sitter expansion $a=a(0)\exp(Ht)$?

I've been told that $H(z)=(1+z)H(0)$ for an exponential de Sitter type expansion, where $H(0)$ is today's expansion rate, Hubble's constant. But is it really just constant $H(z)=H$?

If it is $(1+z)H(0)$,  then why is that?